# Why does Gephi map Neo4j reference node id 0 to 1

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I'm using gephi to visualize my graphs out of neo4j.

I'm using this java snippet to traverse all the nodes in DFS order and print out the node IDs.

```
Traverser dfs = node.traverse(Order.DEPTH_FIRST, StopEvaluator.END_OF_GRAPH,
                                    ReturnableEvaluator.ALL,
                                    MyRelationshipTypes.D, Direction.BOTH);

for( Node n : dfs ) {
        System.out.print( n.getId() );
        printNodeProperties( n );
    }
```

Let's say my graph has 221 nodes in Neo4j from node ID 1 to 222 (since 0 is the reference node).

When I look at the Gephi DataLaboratory I see node IDs 2 to 223 as my graph. Gephi seems to map the reference node ID 0 (Neo4j) to ID 1 (Gephi). Can I prevent this? Why does Gephi do this?